# Image Map links not working with JQuery hide() and show() methods

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, imagemap

I have multiple divs containing various imagemaps. Unfortunately, only the starting image is visible using `style:block` and rest are invisible using `style:none`.

I want to click on a link to change the visible pic to the very next pic with its image map links.

Everything seems fine but when the transition of the image happens using `show()` and `hide()` methods of jQuery, the next imagemap displays without its links working.

They work when I change the window size. Until then, they do not work as links.

The co-ordinated are working grt.

```
<div id="aftermarketSlide" style="display:block">
    <img id='auto_uses_aftermarket' src="images/aket.jpg"  alt="Auto" usemap="#auto_uses_aftermarket1"/>    
        <map id="auto_uses_aftermarket1" name="auto_uses_aftermarket1">
            <area id="Refrigerants" shape="rect" alt="text." title="Refrigerants" coords="121,67,200,82" href="#" target="" />
        </map>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I am trying to, but the indentation error is not letting me, could you tell me where I could attach the code file directly?

Comment: Make sure to have a blank line between the beginning of your code and any text.

Comment: Please refer the link mentioned : http://jsfiddle.net/amitcv86/fPhz9/

Comment: I just updated the code I had posted 5 hours ago. It's much more optimized and easier to implement and alter.

Comment: Where's the link that toggles the images in your fiddle?

Comment: You click on the image itself. Oh god, I just reread his original proposal. Let me fix that.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/amitcv86/fPhz9  (here - panel have been added for doing the same)

Comment: thnkx Jack. Plz do it by using images. As the links on the imagemaps doenst work when using hide() or show(). The links gets disabled. Plz let me know when you achieve the same.

Comment: @JackCole have you found any solution to my problem???